# How to do filtering and sorting on “Pages by URL” in Experience Analytics

Tags: experience-analytics, tracking

Here are my business requirements:

1. I want to track the most visited pages during the last month
2. I want to track the particular page in the Experience analytics

I am not able to find any sorting or filtering functionality in the experience analytics to achieve these requirements, I have to go one by one to track the page URLs/Items.

Is there any way I can search the particular URL/Item by providing the Item Id or URL and can track the specific page?

Note - I am using Sitecore 9 version

[image]

Answer (score 3):

At least the first of your requirements can easily be achieved by changing default sorting  options for the list.

For the 'By URL' detailed list, you can find the default settings in item
`/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceAnalytics/Dashboard/Behavior/Pages/By URL/PageSettings/ListControl Parameters` in the core database

`KeysSortByMetric` - determines the values to be sorted

`KeysSortDirection` - determines the sort order for the values specified in `KeysSortByMetric`

I guess the following default values is what you are looking for

```
KeysSortByMetric = Visits
KeysSortDirection = Descending
```

Enabling searching or filtering by a page path seems to require major changes in code. I just wonder if you can go with a more simple workaround, e.g. change the default Page Size the 'By URL' detailed list and use default browser search to find something on the page. In order to set Page Size use field `KeysCount`